# Power calculation from E and H field

Tags: power, rfid, em

I am using gprMax to simulate my design. The design is shown in the picture. It consists of an RFID system inside a steel structure. The transmitting antenna is placed in the middle of the container and the receiving antenna (RFID tag) is sandwiched in between a block of plastic and wood (purple box and pink box in the corner respectively). The second picture shows the E and H field at the receiving antenna.

I know that an RFID tag requires about 30 to 100uW of power to turn on. Is there a way that I can use the E and H field at the receiver to somehow convert it to power so I can see if the RFID tag is been turned on?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Poynting vector \$\bf S\$ is given by
$${\bf S} = {\bf E}\times{\bf H}$$
The magnitude of the Poynting vector gives the *intensity* of the electromagnetic wave. That is the, the power per unit area.

To get the received power from this you must average over time and integrate \$\bf S\$ over the effective aperture area of your antenna, multiplying for the *directive gain* of the antenna at its orientation to the Poynting vector, if it is not aligned ideally.

Comment: Can you assist on showing how I calculate this? My effective area is 0.013539m^2

Comment: Very crudely, multiply \$|{\bf S}|\$ by that area and by a \$\cos \theta\$ factor to account for the orientation of the antenna relative to the direction of \$\bf S\$.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening but there's a formating issue with the equation. Can you include it in your answer? Maybe it will fix it.

Comment: @Joey try reloading the page.

Comment: Tried that already. Still having issues. Think it's just me then if you not seeing that issue. The answer appears fine, just the comment is not

Comment: Without Mathjax: P = A |S| cos(theta). Where A is your aperture area and theta is the angle of the aperture normal relative to S. (If you know the directivity function of your antenna, use that instead of cos theta)

Comment: can you provide of where I can get this equations from specifically the P= A |S| cos(thetha)?

Comment: By where I mean the site or book. I have been trying to lookup that equation (P = A |S| cos...) but I cannot find it. Please assist me has I need the full derivation of it.

Comment: That's just what you get when you integrate over an area small enough that S doesn't vary much over the area.

Comment: Another way to look at it, is that the effective aperture of the antenna is defined to make this equation work. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture), " The aperture is defined as the area, oriented perpendicular to the direction of an incoming electromagnetic wave, which would intercept the same amount of power from that wave as is produced by the antenna receiving it."

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for worrying you, I have included the calculation on a new post linked to this. Can you check if my calculations are correct?