# Power received by RFID tag

Tags: power, rfid, em

[Power calculation from E and H field](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481072/power-calculation-from-e-and-h-field/481075?noredirect=1#comment1222650_481075)

Following from the previous post above. The user provided me with some assistance however I am still a bit unclear on how to apply the equations provided. Could someone please assist me in determining if the way I calculated the power received from the RFID tag is correct?

Ex = 0, Ey = 0, Ez = 149 (V/m)

Hx = 0.06, Hy = 0.834, Hz = 0 (A/m)

S = E X H = (-124.27 ; 8.94 ; 0)

|S| = 124.59

P = Aperture area x |S| x cos(theta)

P = 0.013539 x 124.59 x cos(38.54) = 1.32W

The aperture area is 0.013539 meters^2.

The angle was calculated using the picture attached. Is this the correct way of calculating the angle?

[image]

Comment: The area is defined by the aperture of the antenna and not some simple physical measurement. Go google antenna aperture.

Comment: @Andyaka the aperture area was calculated using the frequency and gain of the antenna

Comment: Ok my mistake. I think you need to make that clearer in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka I updated the question. Is my working out correct?

Comment: It hasn’t updated yet but I expect someone will point out if not.

Comment: @Andyaka I only changed area to aperture area. The values did not change. So the working out remains the same, just the word/ variable area is now aperture area.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the *aperture* of the antenna is

> The aperture is defined as the area, oriented perpendicular to the direction of an incoming electromagnetic wave, which would intercept the same amount of power from that wave as is produced by the antenna receiving it.

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture))

So if you know the aperture of the antenna, you already know, by definition, the area which, when multiplied by the intensity of the electromagnetic wave, gives the power received by the antenna.

If the antenna isn't oriented perpendicular to the incoming wave, you'll need to multiply by an additional factor to account for that. If you know the radiation pattern of the antenna, you can calculate the orientation factor from that.

The \$\cos\theta\$ factor I used in the previous answer assumes the antenna acts more or less like an actual aperture --- that its directive gain falls off to zero when oriented parallel to the incoming wave. If your antenna is isotropic (for example), then this is a completely wrong assumption. In general you should use the actual radiation pattern of your antenna to find the directive gain for this calculation.

Comment: From the picture the antenna is not orientated perpendicular to it. So I included the cos(theta) factor to account for this. And the theta was calculated has shown in the picture. The RFID TAG is parallel to the longest side of the container and the angle was thus calculated. Is this calculation correct?

Comment: If you're going to use \$\cos\theta\$ as an approximation, you should take \$\theta\$ as the angle to the normal, not the angle you showed.

Comment: So just take 90-38.45 degrees?

Comment: Yes, but I realized I don't know the actual main lobe direction of your antenna, so maybe it's something else.

Comment: It's just a simulation for now so I assumed the main lobe direction is at 0 degrees. Upon practical testing I will see how much the deviation is from the simulations and will then account for the main lobe direction. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I'm getting confused in your last paragraph of the answer. When you say if my antenna is isotropic are you referring to the transmitter or receiver antenna. The transmission antenna radiates power according to the picture in the previous post. The receiver or rfid tag, is simulated as a receiver that just records the e and h field values it doesn't transmit and power back.

Comment: The receiving antenna. The receiving directive gain pattern is identical to the transmitting radiation pattern (due to "reciprocity").

Comment: From the pic I do believe the transmitter antenna is an isotropic antenna because the intensity is the same from - 180 to +180 degrees from the previous post. The receiver in the picture isn't actually and antenna is just a sensor and I called it to be a rfid tag for descriptive purposes. I calculated the aperture area based on a rfid tag gain I will be using in testing, however that data sheet does not have the directivity field pattern. So I assumimg its at 0 degrees for simulation purposes. Does this mean everything is therefore wrong?

Comment: I'd say it means you're only going to be able to find an upper limit on your received power.

Comment: That's definitely a good thing then. Because that therefore means that my simulations is the best case scenario. So if the power isn't enough in the simulations then I can confidently predict that it won't work in the real world because my transmitter is not going to be an isotropic antenna. Is this assumption true?

Comment: If you're not simulating with an accurate transmitter antenna model, I think your simulation is useless, because it won't tell you anything about how you excite the box where your two antennas are located.

Comment: I have changed the setup of the simulation the RFID tag will now be the transmitter and the transmitter will now become a receiver. The software does have a dipole antenna which simulates the RFID tag perfectly. It doesn't have a patch antenna simulator. This was a clear and stupid oversight on my part.